# cargo rust build script - print output of command

Tags: rust, command, rust-cargo, build-script

I am new to rust and cargo, and I am trying to do something very simple!

I have something like this (in build.rs):

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    Command::new("echo 123");
}
```

And I want to see the output of the command `echo 123`. I want `123` to get printed to the build output (this is mostly to debug what I am doing) and wont be part of the final project.

I have tried `cargo build --verbose` - this does not work.

I can't extrapolate an answer from there posts (and some others like it):

- https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/985
- https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1106

I feel this must be simple to do - but I have been stuck for hours looking on the web and not finding the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just building a `Command` with [`Command::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.new) does not execute it yet. It just starts a builder pattern. To actually execute it, you have to use the methods [`spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn), [`output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output) or [`status`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status). Example:

```rust
Command::new("echo")
    .arg("123")
    .spawn()
    .expect("failed to spawn process");
```

It's very unfortunate that this doesn't produce a warning. Someone [recently tried to add the `#[must_use]` attribute to `Command`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/81452), which would make your code procude a warning. The PR closed for now but it seems like it will be added eventually.

Comment: Thanks, good to know about the command not running! - But I still do not get any output here (even if I copy/paste your answer in). I added the argument `> test.out` - and no `test.out` file was generated. I also tried with state and output... any clues?

Comment: @code_fodder Oops, I kinda forgot about that part of the question. As mentioned in the first issue you linked, `cargo build -vv` does show the output of the build script. The output is also shown with a normal `cargo build` if the build script exits with a non 0 exit code. So `std::process::exit(1)` will also show the output. (Of course, only use that if there is an actual error.)

Comment: ah ha, great thanks. I Was still trying `--verbose` :)

Comment: Is there any way to debug build.rs file?

Answer (score 4):

We can use a macro and it worked form me, but there is a warning, since it uses cargo to display. but that is fine for me.
I found below code from git hub discussion:
[Cargo doesn’t display output from a command in build.rs #985](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/985#issuecomment-1071667472)

```
macro_rules! p {
    ($($tokens: tt)*) => {
        println!("cargo:warning={}", format!($($tokens)*))
    }
}

fn main() {
    p!("BUILD.rs -> Starting ...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `-vv` option with cargo, lets you see the output from the build scripts.
For more information, refer [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-script-examples.html).

So, you can store the output of the command in a string, and then possibly write out using println.